# backbone.js: encapsulating view functions?

Tags: backbone.js

Pretty new to **backbone.js** so forgive me of my ignorance. I'm wondering, is there a way to encapsulate functions within the View class specifically?

I ask because when setting default `events`...

```
events {
   'click .something' : 'doSomething'
}
```

... I'd prefer to have `doSomething` be nested in an encapsulating object for optimal organization. For example:

```
ui: {
    doSomething: function() {}
}
```

But then I can't seem to get the default `events` to work.

```
events {
    'click .something' : 'ui.doSomething' // this doesn't work
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Or, if you can tell me why I shouldn't be doing this then I'd appreciate that, as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the source that binds the events (`delegateEvents`) which is called from the constructor, it is pretty clear that it works on variables with in the scope of the object.

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-118

You could, however, override `delegateEvents` to be a bit smarter... You could parse the value for dots and chain your tokens.  You could even check the type of the value and use an actual function in place of the string.  That might give you better control the way you want.

More info on the `delegateEvents` function: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-delegateEvents